# Injecting Class<T> using guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm working toward implementing DI, specifically constructor injection using guice. I'm having difficulty understanding how I can inject the type of the class for a generic into the constructor.

My class is as follows:

```
public class Foo<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

Can I use guice to inject the type of the class into the constructor at runtime? Simply put, Can I use guice to inject into the Foo constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using Guice's [built-in injection](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BuiltInBindings) of [`TypeLiteral`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html)s.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();

        Test<Integer> testInt = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Test<Integer>>() {}));
        testInt.action();

        Test<String> testString = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Test<String>>() {}));
        testString.action();
    }

    public static class Test<T> {
        private final Class<? super T> clazz;

        @Inject
        public Test(TypeLiteral<T> literal) {
            this.clazz = literal.getRawType();
        }

        public void action() {
            System.out.println(clazz);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure why `getRawType()` returns `Class<? super T>`, not `Class<T>`, though.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Class<SomeClass>>() {}).toInstance(SomeClass.class);
```

to configure Guice to inject `SomeCLass.class` into the constructor of

`Foo<SomeClass>`